# Displays but does not print?

Tags: c#

I am trying to print a document like shown below

The title in bold and the rest of the text in regular font style. This is the print preview!

The problem is, after printing, the title in bold does not display but space is left for it. How to fix this?

[image]

I have written the following class to print that document.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace documentPrinter
{
    public partial class documentPrinter : PrintDocument
    {
        public String documenTitle { get; set; }
        public String doContent { get; set; }
        String contenToPrint;
        public Font contentFont { get; set; }
        public Font titleFont { get; set; }
        bool prinTitle = true;

        protected override void OnQueryPageSettings(QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e)
        {
            PageSettings PgS = e.PageSettings;
            PgS.Color = false;
            PgS.Landscape = false;
            PgS.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            PgS.Margins = new Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            //base.OnQueryPageSettings(e);
        }

        protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            contenToPrint = "\n\n\n" + doContent;
            //base.OnBeginPrint(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int charactersOnPage = 0;
            int linesPerPage = 0;

            // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters  
            // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.

            if (prinTitle)
            {
                e.Graphics.MeasureString(documenTitle, 
                                         titleFont,
                                         e.MarginBounds.Size,
                                         StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
                                         out charactersOnPage,
                                         out linesPerPage);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(documenTitle, 
                                      titleFont,
                                      Brushes.Black,
                                      e.MarginBounds,
                                      StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
                prinTitle = false;
            }

            e.Graphics.MeasureString(contenToPrint,
                                     contentFont,
                                     e.MarginBounds.Size,
                                     StringFormat.GenericTypographic, 
                                     out charactersOnPage,
                                     out linesPerPage);

            // Draws the string within the bounds of the page.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(contenToPrint, contentFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
            contenToPrint = contenToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage); 

            // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
            e.HasMorePages = (contenToPrint.Length > 0);

            //base.OnPrintPage(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway, I think I found out something, I changed the if condition into a while loop. I think that works fine now! Thanks !

Comment: Your content over-draws the title.  You need to fix the DrawString() call, it can't be e.MarginsBounds.